# Accessing packages from subdirectory

Tags: java, package

I was working on this assignment and they gave us this UML - one package was named `maze` and had a bunch of classes. the other was named `maze.routing`. I looked up how to work with this so I'm not sure if what I have done is right and I'm getting many errors as well.

In every class in the `maze` package, I added a `package maze;` statement and placed these classes inside a folder named `maze`.

I created a folder named routing inside the folder named `maze`. Inside the classes in `maze.routing`, I added a package statement and an `import` statement:

```
package maze.routing;
import maze.*
```

The classes in `maze` compile fine but when I try to compile the classes in the `maze/routing` folder I get an error. What's happening?

edit: I am so sorry this was my bad - i should have been running it from the main directory which contains maze

Comment: Are you directly using the jdk or are you using an IDE? If you're using the jdk directly, compile everything while still in the first directory.

Comment: @NomadMaker i used cmd prompt to compile and run

Comment: Did you compile all the java files, including the ones in the subdirectories, from the same directory?

Comment: @NomadMaker i did run it from the first directory -- first I did javac \*.java and then i did javac routing\\*.java

Comment: Where did the class files for the routing files go?

Comment: Please always try and format your questions to the best of your abilities, and **always always** specify the **full error** including the line that spawned it. For inline code you only need one back-tick by the way, not three.

Comment: I suspect that you need to tell the compiler where to put the class files. When I compile from the command line, I use something like this: 'javac -d ./ *.java routing/*.java' The "-d ./" tells the compiler to put the class files in a directory structure starting at the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added `package maze;` and `package maze.routing;` in the respective classes, you do not need to create the folders. Java compiler will automatically create the folders for you. See the demo below:

**A.java:**

```
package maze;

public class A{
}
```

**B.java:**

```
package maze.routing;
import maze.*;
public class B{
}
```

Both `A.java` and `B.java` are at the same location (i.e. in the same folder). Now, in the command prompt/terminal window if you use the following command from this location/folder:

```
javac -d . *.java
```

the classes will be compiled and put into respective package/folders as well.

**Note:** The option, `.` denotes the current folder.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since I don’t see much difference other than verbosity of it.